# Graph theory, all paths with given distance

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, np-hard

So I found a problem where a traveller can travel a certain distance in a graph and all bidirectional edges have some length(distance). Suppose when travelling a certain edge(either direction) you get some money/gift (it's given in question for all edges)so you have to find the max money you can collect for the given distance you can travel. Basic problem is how do I find all possible paths with given distance (there might be loops in graph) and after finding all possible paths, path with max money collected will simply be the answer. Note: any possible paths you come up with should not have a loop (straight path).

Comment: Starting and ending nodes are given or needs to be optimised as well?

Comment: not given .. optimise over all sources and destinations for which path length is given number in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are given an undirected connected graph with double weight on the edges (distance and reward).
You are given a fixed number d corresponding to a possible distance.

For each couple of nodes (u,v), u not equal to v, you are looking for

- All the paths {P_j} connecting u and v with no repeating nodes whose total distance is d.
- The paths {P_hat(j)} subset of {P_j} whose reward is maximal.

To get the first, I would try to use a modified version of the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, where you do not look for the shortest, but for any path. 
Floyd-Warshall uses a strategy based on considering a "middle node" w between u and v and recursively finds the path minimising the distance between u and v.

You can do the same, while taking all path instead of excluding the minimisation, taking care of putting to `inf` the nodes where you have already b visited in the distance matrix and excluding at runtime every partial path in the recursion whose distance is longer than d or that arrives to an end (they connects u and v) and whose distance is shorter than d.

Can be generalised if an interval of possible distances [d, D] is given, instead of a single value d, as in this second case you would probably get the empty set all the time.

For the second step, you simply compare the reward of each of the path found in solving the first step, and you take the best one.

Is more a suggested direction rather than a complete answer, but I hope it helps!